# How can i implement this code in postgresql using psql?

Tags: postgresql

How would i implement this code in postgresql using psql?

```
Declare @Id int
Set @Id = 1

While @Id <= 100
Begin 
   Insert Into tblAuthors values ('Author - ' + CAST(@Id as nvarchar(10)),
              'Country - ' + CAST(@Id as nvarchar(10)) + ' name')
   Print @Id
   Set @Id = @Id + 1
End
```

I've tried to search some tutorials for postgresql syntax but none of them works.

Comment: Don't make it that complicated. Don't use an imperative loop. Write plain SQL and use the [`generate_series` function to generate 100 rows of data](https://www.citusdata.com/blog/2018/03/14/fun-with-sql-generate-sql/) to insert at once.

Comment: You might also be interested in this: https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/154251

Answer (score 0):

No need for  PL/pgSQL, a loop or variables:

```
insert into tblauthors (name, country)
select concat('Author - ',id),
       concat('Country - ',id,' name')
from generate_series(1,100) as g(id);
```

Comment: thank you! do you recommend some material i can study to learn this better? I need to know also how to allow the script to get user input to define how many tables it will generate

Comment: Plpgsql in non-interactive. It **cannot** get user input. That will have to come from your bash script or other scripting language, or from your apps interface as a parameter (to function/procedure), or dynamic construction of the SQL in the app.

Answer (score 0):

The answer by @a_horse_with_no_name is correct, a single insert is all that is required. However, your question seems more about syntax rather than how to accomplish. So let's review; some observations necessary to convert your code to Postgres.

1. The language is `plpgsql` not `psql`. `Psql` in the command line interface application into `Postgresql` database management system.
2. `@` is not a valid character in an object name.
3. Declaration of a variable requires specification of the data type.
4. `Set` not used for variable assignment. If used it establishes/changes the run-time environment
5. Variable initialization can occur when variable is defined.
6. There in no `nvarchar` data type. Just use `text`.
7. There is no `Print` statement. Use `raise notice` instead.
8. `+` is not used for string concatenation. Use either the function `concat()` or the operator (`||`).
9. Each statement must terminate with a semi-colon (`;`).
10. Loops are enclosed by `loop ... end loop;`
11. All statements, other than declarations, must be enclosed within
    `begin ... end;`.
12. The entire code block must be enclosed in single quotes or a
    Dollar-Quoted String Constant.
13. All code blocks must be within a Function, a Procedure, a Do block, or within another code block.
14. While not required it is best to always specify column names on
    Inserts. (IMHO is should be required).

Accounting for the above your code becomes:

```
DO $BLK$          -- A Dollar-Quoted String Constant 
declare 
  id integer = 1;

begin 
    while id <= 100
    loop
        insert into tblauthors (name, country)
             values ( 'author - ' || cast(id as text)
                    , 'country - '  || cast(id as text) || ' name'
                    ); 
        raise notice '%', cast(id as text); 
        id = id + 1;
    end loop;
end; $BLK$;
```

Instead of a *search some tutorials* a good place to start would be the [Documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/index.html). More specifically perhaps the chapter [Lexical Structure](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-syntax-lexical.html)

NOTE: #2 above is not strictly true. You can us `@` in a variable name if it is enclosed in double quotes as `"@name"`. However, double quotes become a read pia very quickly and are best avoided completely.